# maven/eclipse dependency help please

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I just tried to update my JFreeChart in Maven from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jfreechart</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.15</version>
</dependency>
```

On Maven Project Update - it says it can't find the artifact.

SO I TRIED TO GO BACK by editting the POM again to the old dependency.

Now on Maven Update it still says it can't find 1.0.15 artifact!!!!
In BuildPath>Libraries>Maven Dependencies   jFreeChart1.0.15 is still should BUT all buttons are disabled so I can't remove it.

Comment: try `Ctrl-F5` on your project (in eclipse of course)

Comment: Stupid suggestion: mvn clean and then mvn clean install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your project, then click on Maven->Update Project. Should help.

Comment: Well that sort of worked I had to do it several times

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure your maven plugin to use maven [central repository](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jfree%7Cjfreechart%7C1.0.15%7Cjar).